# Retrieve customer related to payment

Tags: square, square-connect

Anyone know if it's possible to retrieve the customer name related to a transaction from the API?

I see it under "Paid by" if I follow the "payment_url" in the connect v1 `https://connect.squareup.com/v1/{{location_id}}/payments/{{payment_id}}` endpoint but can't see to find it anywhere else

Background: I'm working on a ticketing system that breaks out items by item_category so a kitchen gets *only* food items and the bar gets *only* drink items.

I have queues and itemized tickets by category BUT I can't seem to find the customer's name anywhere

Comment: Did you ever bulk import with qty? @ Dan

Comment: I did not! I found the slack group pretty helpful with questions though

From the bottom of their developer docs: https://squ.re/2Hks3YE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to utilize the V2 `Transactions` API. When you call `ListTransactions` or `RetrieveTransaction` ([ListTransactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions)), the `Transaction` object will have an array of Tenders, `tenders`, which has a field called `customer_id`. With this id, you will be able to pass it to `RetrieveCustomer` ([RetrieveCustomer)](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-retrievecustomer) to find out their name. Note that if you're not explicitly filling out their name, the name might not be available (an "instant profile" ([Instant Profiles](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/growth/customers/overview#instant-profiles)) will be created with whatever information can be retrieve from the card used to pay).

Update: Alternatively, as suggested by @Dan, would be to strip the `payment_url` from a V1 `RetrievePayment` ([RetrievePayment](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-paymentid)) which includes the `transaction_id` at the end of the URL: `https://squareup.com/dashboard/sales/transactions/TRANSACTION_ID`. This is more efficient as you won't need to loop through transactions, and allow you to send it straight to `RetrieveTransaction`.

Comment: Thanks!

Rather than looping through `ListTransactions`, I discovered that the related transaction_id is at the end of the payment's RESTful  `payment_url`. As such I can go straight for `RetrieveTransaction` using a `spilt("/")` and `pop()`

@sjosey Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am using squareup, how can i import products with qty, if i import with qty it does not take my qty, how to solve this error, i need to import products with qty, is possible with API? @ sjosey

Comment: @Rathinam your best bet is to ask on the slack channel. They're pretty quick to  respond!